# Fast extracting of large number of small tar archives

Tags: c#, archive, tar, compression

I have a large number of small tar archives (around 50kb each). I need the fastest way how to extract these files using C#. I don't want to save them to disk, becase I have to do some other processing of the content after extracting. I tried to do it on my own but the processing was not very fast. Could you please advice me the fastest way to process the tar files?

Comment: Which is it?  Fast _extracting_ or fast _"processing"_?   If it's the latter then you'll need to tell us exactly what processing you're attempting

Comment: The best method would depend the method that was used to create the tar.  There are different types of tar.  See type flag on following webpage : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing).

Comment: `I tried to do it on my own but the processing was not very fast` - can you show us that code?

Answer (score 0):

> I need the fastest way how to extract these files
>
> I have to do some other processing of the content **after** extracting

Yoiu might want to look into *TPL Dataflow*.   Perfect irrespective of whether the problem is in the *decompressing* or subsequent *processing*. Instead of having one big function, you break it up into multiple connected steps. Essentially Dataflow creates a flow pipeline of connected components for each task step you wish to perform.  Each step has complete control over threading; concurrency.

### More

- *[Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)*